Counting approach for finding probability mass function
I'm going through my notes for my probability course and I'm trying to deduce a probability mass function using standard counting techniques on a discrete random variable.

Here it deduces the probability function $f(x)=\frac{3x^2-3x+1}{216}$ by first computing the CDF, but I also tried acquiring $f(x)$ using just counting techniques to obtain the cardinality of each $X=x$.
My logic goes as follows. For some $X=x$, we can break it into three cases: two repeated rolls, all rolls being equal, and all rolls being distinct.
For the two repeated rolls we have either $x$ being the duplicate and $x-1$ possibilities for the distinct, or the other way which gives us $x-1$ selections each and thus totaling to $2(x-1)$. Permuting these across the 3 dice roll gives $\frac{3!}{2!}2(x-1)=6x-6$
For all rolls being equal we can only get $x$, so this amounts to only $1$ possibility.
For all rolls being distinct, we have $x-1$ and $x-2$ choices for the other two rolls, so we obtain a total selection of $(x-1)(x-2)$ which permutes over all 3 dice rolls to $6(x-1)(x-2)$.
Adding these up gives $6x-6+1+6(x-1)(x-2)=6x^2-12x+7$ which clearly doesn't equal $3x^2-3x+1$. Where did I go wrong?

Well, the formulas match for $x\in {1,2}$ which strongly suggests that the error is in the "three distinct rolls" case.  I suggest:  go through the case $x=3$ line by line.  Of course, if $x=3$ there is only one "all distinct" case up to permutation, namely ${1,2,3}$.

For all rolls being distinct, you are double-counting certain permutations with your current way of counting. You should choose the other two rolls by $\dbinom{x-1}{2}$, and then permute. This gives $6\dbinom{x-1}{2} = 3x^2-9x+6$.
Alternatively, you can also count as follows. First, for the position of $x$, we have $3$ choices. Then, $x-1$ choices for first of the remaining two positions, and then $x-2$ choices for the second of the remaining two positions. This also gives $3(x-1)(x-2) = 3x^2-9x+6$.
